# How to bind Kendo UI AutoComplete values to URLs?

Tags: autocomplete, kendo-ui

How to bind Kendo UI AutoComplete values to URLs?
I use the open source version; [Kendo UI Core](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui/open-source-core).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use template and wrap your content inside an anchor tag.

```
  var autocomplete = $("selector").kendoAutoComplete({ 
                    minLength: 1,
                    dataTextField: "Name",
                    template: '<a href="link">#: Name #</span></a>',
                    dataSource: {//your data source details
                        }
                    }
                }).data("kendoAutoComplete");
            });
```